# Skewing java random number generation toward a certain number

Tags: java, random, numbers

How, in Java, would you generate a random number but make that random number skewed toward a specific number.  For example, I want to generate a number between 1 and 100 inclusive, but I want that number skewed toward say, 75.  But I still want the possibility of getting other numbers in the range, but I want more of a change of getting numbers close to say 75 as opposed to just getting random numbers all across the range.  Thanks

Comment: Do you want integers or real numbers?

Comment: @belisarius I'm curious how the approach would change in a scalable manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()

```
Math.max(1, Math.min(100, (int) 75 + Random.nextGaussian() * stddev)))
```

Pick a stddev like 10 and play around until you get the distribution you want.  There are going to be slightly more at 1 and 100 though than at 2 or 99.  If you want to change the rate at which it drops off, you can raise the gaussian to a power.

Comment: +1 for "There are going to be slightly more at 1 and 100 though than at 2 or 99"

Comment: re-rolling is technically never guaranteed to complete. Unlikely that it won't, but... possible that it won't!

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, I kinda thought it had something to do with nextGaussian() but I was having trouble making heads or tails of it.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Ok, make sure I've got this right, the 1 is the lowest value possible, the 100 is the max value, and 75 is the value to skew the numbers to, right?

Comment: @glowcoder, Given that PRNGs are not really random, the chance of completing may be 1 for some algos and not for others.  With a truly random number generator, it is guaranteed to complete in one sense.  While it is true, that there is no finite number of rolls above which the chance of having seen a number between the limits is 1, the probability of rolling such a number after k rolls approaches 1 as k -> inf.

Comment: @Mike Oh I'm well aware of that. I would not imagine it would ever take more than a few extra iterations in the worst *noticed* case. However, it would not be doing due diligence on our part as developers to not document the fact that, in theory, you could freeze a program by calling it.

Comment: @glowcoder, agreed.  And many PRNGs that aren't cryptographically strong are known to have holes that allow them to be exploited to generate predictable sequences.  An attacker might be able to roll-forward a PRNG to a place where they take a long time to produce a number in a narrow range to deny service.

Comment: @Mike Yep. One way to get around that is to first generate an unskewed, valid random value. If after X amount of attempts to get a skewed random value, you can return the "simple" random value instead. (I guess you could generate it after you max out your allowed iterations, would be better.) In this case you would sacrifice a (very small) amount of your desired distribution properties, but you are safe from attacks/bad luck.

Comment: @glowcoder LOL "you are safe from bad luck". I'll make a poster with that one :D

Comment: @belisarius Oh don't worry - bad luck may lose this battle, but it will always win the war!

Answer (score 21):

Question is a bit old, but if anyone wants to do this without the special case handling, you can use a function like this:

```
    final static public Random RANDOM = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    static public double nextSkewedBoundedDouble(double min, double max, double skew, double bias) {
        double range = max - min;
        double mid = min + range / 2.0;
        double unitGaussian = RANDOM.nextGaussian();
        double biasFactor = Math.exp(bias);
        double retval = mid+(range*(biasFactor/(biasFactor+Math.exp(-unitGaussian/skew))-0.5));
        return retval;
    }
```

The parameters do the following:

- min - the minimum skewed value possible
- max - the maximum skewed value possible
- skew - the degree to which the values cluster around the mode of the distribution; higher values mean tighter clustering
- bias - the tendency of the mode to approach the min, max or midpoint value; positive values bias toward max, negative values toward min

Comment: This. Most useful thing for generative art I've found in ages. Thank you! Is there a source for this?

Comment: You're welcome!  This is just a snippet of code I pulled from one of my side projects.  It's not on github or anything, but it seemed to fit the bill for this question.

Comment: Which formula are you using for that?